# Playing Aion or Tera on a Japanese Server

Tags: tera, aion

I'm at a middle/highschool level of Japanese and I currently live in America. I want to practice my Japanese through through playing a MMORPG so I was thinking of trying to join a Japan Server for Aion or Tera. The problem is that they IP lock. There's a further difficultly in that Tera is owned by different companies for the American server (En Masse in America and Hangame for Japan I think).

I've considered using a proxy but I was afraid that it would slow my connection. Any suggestions on how to get onto a Japanese server or keep the maximal Japanese exposure as an American player?

Comment: Been a long time since I played either but do they not have a language option for the install?

Comment: Not that I am aware of: see http://tera-forums.enmasse.com/forums/general-discussion/topics/Language-options

Comment: Not sure yet about Aion (forums weren't that useful) but I would like to be able to interact with Japanese and play with them. Also, this is off topic to the thread so I apologize in advance but if there is an MMORPG thats free to play, similar to AION or Tera, and the players use lots of voice chatting I would appreciate a quick recommendation in the comments. Again not relevant to thread but it would be nice to know. I might try and move over to that game for Japanese practice if AION or Tera doesn't work out.

Comment: I remember PW used to let you on their Asian servers without IP block, but that was years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [Help Accessing Japanese TERA-Online (Hongfire.com)](http://www.hongfire.com/forum/showthread.php/381142-Help-Accessing-Japanese-TERA-Online)

EDIT:
The download provided in the link above is [here](http://tera.hangame.co.jp/library/download.nhn).
The game will not officially play unless you are in Japan. A way to get around this is to go to Control Panel. Search for Clock, and click Region when it comes up. Navigate to the Location tab and change the drop-down to Japan.

Comment: Please summarize the linked information.  That way, if the page ever goes down, your answer is still valid.  And it saves people a click.

Answer (score -4):

Why, play Final Fantasy XIV, of course! Just create a character on Japanese server (no limitations), and that's it ) You may switch interface and voices to Japanese, too. The game is top-notch and VERY japanese in everything )

Comment: This is not a fórum where you can post your opinión, the question is specificaly for Tera and Aion stick to question